# Code is unable to pick css files in react app

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx

I have kept the buttn.css and button.js in the same folder in my react app.But css is not rendering.

Button.css

```
.Button {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font: inherit;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.Button:first-of-type {
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.Success {
    color: #5C9210;
}

.Danger {
    color: #944317;
}
```

Button.js

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './Button.css';
const Button = (props) => (
  <button
  className={[classes.Button,classes[props.btnType]].join(' ')}
  onClick={props.clicked}>{props.children}</button>
);

export default Button;
```

Please suggest how to proceed without having to make a common css sheet for all the elements.

Comment: How have you attempted to debug so far? Have you `console.log`'d what `[classes.Button,classes[props.btnType]].join(' ')` evaluates to? Have you used browser dev tools to see if any of the CSS classes are being applied?

Comment: No, browser is unable to discover the css class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) your css file [should be named Button.module.css](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/).